# Upload PDF file using PHP failed

Tags: php, file-upload

I can't upload my PDF file, even I have tried some tips from google.
But, My php upload still not work. I have changed the folder permission to `777`.

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="uploader.php" method="POST"> 
<input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="3500000" />
Upload File: <input name="uploadedfile" type="file" />
<input type="submit" value="Upload File" />
</form>

$target_path = "/home/jeinqa/www/apps/upload/";

$target_path = $target_path . basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']);
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) {
        echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']). " has been uploaded";
                }
        else{
                echo "There was an error uploading the file, please try again!";
                }
```

show : 
`There was an error uploading the file, please try again!`

---

try to use `print_r($_FILES);` :

```
Array ( [uploadedfile] => Array ( [name] => SOP-31 KW-HDR81BTJD.pdf [type] => [tmp_name] => [error] => 2 [size] => 0 ) ) There was an error uploading the file, please try again!
```

Comment: Any error messages you would like to share? It's impossible to help you with the provided info. This "question" just states: "it doesn't work, hallup"

Comment: Which `echo` from `if(move_uploaded_file` part gets into count?

Comment: write 2 echos, one for the target_path, one for $_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'], are they ok?

Comment: I'm copy this script from some tutorial sites.So,this is the 1st time I'm using this php upload.

Comment: are you sure that your file is < 10KB ? And you didn't use that `max file size` anywhere

Comment: just after submitting, `print_r($_FILES)` and check that all the variables You use are correct... Also, do You get some error message like `warning`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Does your folder has 777 permission (and all sub-folders)?
2. Do you have safe_mode enabled in PHP.ini?
3. Your MAX_FILE_SIZE is 10 KB but I doubt your file is this small please check your file size.
4. Does the target_path exists?
5. Try changing your target_path from absolute to relative it will probably become: upload.

**Update**

Your file is to big! Just change the max size!
See http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php for more information.

Your error: Value: 2; The uploaded file exceeds the MAX_FILE_SIZE directive that was specified in the HTML form.

Comment: is that better if I not mention MAX FILE?

Comment: I don't think it matters any simple programmer can just inject another value in MAX_FILE_SIZE. I suggest checking the file_size with PHP. So yes you can remove the input field: <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="3500000" />

Comment: thank for your advise, after try step no 1 & 5 and delete MAX_FILE all can work.